# My output isnt what it need to be

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  1  def HelloWorld(mystring):
  2     print(mystring)
  3     myname = input("what is your name?")
  4     myVar = input("Enter a number:")
  5     if(myname == "ofir" and myVar == 0):
  6        print("ofir is great!")
  7     elif(myname == "bob"):
  8        print("bob is ok")
  9     else:
  10       print("All is ok")   
  11  HelloWorld("Hello function")
```

That what I have written,When I input myname =ofir and myvar=0 (in cmd) I get "All is ok" why I dont get "ofir is great!".

Comment: You are testing for an integer, but `myVar` is a string object.

Comment: `myVar = int(raw_input("Enter a number:"))`